# tigris R Maps: Issues with Guam and Mariana Islands Maps

Tags: r, mapping, polygon, census, tigris

I'm having trouble with the **tigris** shape files for Guam and the Mariana Islands:

1. The **tigris** Guam map provides no municipality information however many census datasets include municipalities for Guam. The **tigris**  documentation includes reference to the municipalities. Can anyone recommend another source for Guam municipality polygon/shapefiles?
2. The Mariana Islands are not downloaded correctly using the **counties** function in **tigris**. I have included my work-around but I would prefer to be able to access this information directly.

.

```
library(tigris)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(dplyr)

## Working Puerto Rico Map ----
# Downloads map
PR_map <- counties(72, cb = T) 
# Converts shapefile for ggplot2
PR_map <- ggplot2::fortify(PR_map, region = "COUNTYFP")
# Adds random data
PR_map <- merge(PR_map, data.frame(id = unique(PR_map$id), value = rep(1:4, (length(unique(PR_map$id)) %/% 4 + 4))[1:length(unique(PR_map$id))]), by = "id")
# Plots map
ggplot(PR_map)+geom_map(map = PR_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = value, map_id=id), color="white", size=0.25)+ coord_map("mercator")+ theme_map()

## Broken Guam Map (No municipalities)----
# Downloads map
GU_map <- counties(66, cb = T) 
# Converts shapefile for ggplot2
GU_map <- ggplot2::fortify(GU_map, region = "COUNTYFP")
# Adds random data
GU_map <- merge(GU_map, data.frame(id = unique(GU_map$id), value = rep(1:4, (length(unique(GU_map$id)) %/% 4 + 4))[1:length(unique(GU_map$id))]), by = "id")
# Plots map
ggplot(GU_map)+geom_map(map = GU_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = value, map_id=id), color="white", size=0.25)+ coord_map("mercator")+ theme_map()

## Broken Call for Mariana Islands 
# Does not download Mariana Islands, instead it downloads the entire United States and Territories 
USA_map <- counties(69, cb = T) 

# My work around is to subset to the appropriate region:
MI_map <- subset(USA_map, USA_map$STATEFP == "69")

# Converts shapefile for ggplot2
MI_map <- ggplot2::fortify(MI_map, region = "COUNTYFP")
# Adds random data
MI_map <- merge(MI_map, data.frame(id = unique(MI_map$id), value = rep(1:4, (length(unique(MI_map$id)) %/% 4 + 4))[1:length(unique(MI_map$id))]), by = "id")
# Plots map (The hex turns the map sideways for better viewing.)
ggplot(MI_map)+geom_map(map = MI_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill = value, map_id=id), color="white", size=0.25)+ coord_map("hex")+ theme_map()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Solution to Guam question is to use the "places" function.
2. Bug fixed. Kyle Walker, the maintainer of **tigris**, updated the app in response to this post and the associated tweet. See [tweet.](https://twitter.com/kyle_e_walker/status/983366606964379649)